# javascript decrypt crypto-js from ruby openssl

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

I am attempting to encrypt in ruby and decrypt in javascript. In ruby, I'm using the openssl module, and in javascript I'm using the crypto-js library.

I can encrypt and decrypt using the following code in Ruby:

```
def decrypt_with_aes (key, encrypted_message)
 message = Base64.decode64(encrypted_message)
 aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
 aes.decrypt
 aes.key = key[:key] || key['key']
 aes.iv = key[:iv] || key['iv']
 # output result
 aes.update(message) + aes.final
end

def encrypt_with_aes(key, message)
 aes = OpenSSL::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
 aes.encrypt
 aes.key = key[:key] || key['key']
 aes.iv = key[:iv] || key['iv']
 # output result
 Base64.encode64(aes.update(message) + aes.final)
end
```

I am using the following key and iv

```
{ key: 
    {
      key: '3f9390ea971d68b82ecab512cbeb073a0a399157dbe22e4d3054c0f1f8c0037a'
      iv: 'aba3ac43cf8befcb4678570abb17b6d0'
     }
}
```

Regards of the text I attempt to encrypt, when I try to use the same key & iv to decrypt via crypto-js I get an empty string returned. Please help.

```
function decrypt(encryptedtext, key){

    return  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
               CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedtext),                  
               CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key['key']), {iv: 
               CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key['iv'])}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you parsing the data you're giving to the decrypt function? Have you tried to give the decrypt function raw data without Base64 parsing?

Comment: I tried both ways without much luck

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/issues/detail?id=91) Issue on CryptoJS's google groups forum